# Getting permission denied while Posting xml using Curl?

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have to post a xml to a url to be consumed by some web service. I am using Cent OS 5.6 Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS). When I post from command line using `curl-d@"abc.xml" http://example.com` It gives me result. But when I post from php using curl

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

It gives me curl error `permission denied`. Any idea why I am getting this from code while able to access the url from CLI using `curl -d`. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post the full error, For example is it `ERROR 7 Failed to connect to Permission denied` ?. Since you are in Centos maybe SELinux is the problem. In this case I an guessing that SELinux blocks all the requests from apache to the outer world.

Comment: I am not getting any code. just getting Failed to connect to 10.80.184.195: Permission denied

Comment: Thats fine, try to issue the following command `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1 ` this will allow curl to connect through httpd. Also you can check the status of httpd SELinux policy with this `getsebool -a | grep httpd | grep off$` command

Comment: Sorry to ask again.I have not root access to run this command. I have raised a ticket to the concern person he will check and revert. But one thing is that i am able to curl another API's from same server and same code. All other are workign fine.

Comment: You did not mentioned that everything else work fine, in that case maybe is not a SELinux misconfiguration problem.

Comment: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1 solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solve my problem

```sh
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Comment: This helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672070/php-curl-to-localhost-returns-permission-denied-on-an-open-port/46678301#46678301