# Php curl is active but curl_exec always returns false

Tags: php, curl, centos8

I'm trying to get data from external website using `cURL` in PHP but it's not working.

CURL is enabled in `phpinfo()`.

My test code is not working in `CentOS 8/nginx server` where the `$result=FALSE`, but works fine in `Debian9/nginx`.

```
$ch=curl_init ("http://somogyivakok.hu/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

> cURL Version is 7.61.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Debugging Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and i'd love to know how you solved it

Answer (score 2):

The resource you're looking for is not at **somogyivakok.hu** but at **www.somogyivakok.hu**. So you can use the correct uri or instruct the script to follow redirects using the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option as per the following example:

```php
$ch = curl_init ("http://somogyivakok.hu/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Update:**

Investigating further, despite the issue with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, as `curl_exec` returned `false` there is also an issue with the server configuration and more precisely with `httpd_can_network_connect`.
Using `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to debug the following is logged:

```
Immediate connect fail for 1.1.1.1: Permission denied
```

On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672070/php-curl-to-localhost-returns-permission-denied-on-an-open-port/46678301) we've found the solution is to run the following command on the server shell:

```sh
sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Comment: No, that's not the case.

Comment: Definitely the case as I actually tested my code :) Without CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION I was getting an empty string indeed. `http://somogyivakok.hu/` is redirecting with a 301 to `http://www.somogyivakok.hu/` (Ps. If you're using Chrome the www part is hidden by the browser).

Comment: Btw, I've just realized that if `curl_exec` returns false there might be some other error. Could you use `curl_error` and provide the returned error (check the first example [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php))?

Comment: `Curl_error` returns an empty string. I also debugged with `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` returns the following:
`Trying 94.199.183.214...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 94.199.183.214: Permission denied
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: The return value is missing on your last comment... also other than `curl_error` could you return also `curl_errno` output (more info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php))?

Comment: Alright, this seems a different problem alltogether. Have you already checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672070/php-curl-to-localhost-returns-permission-denied-on-an-open-port/46678301) ?

Comment: Thanks MiCc83 your last thread is solved the problem. How can I indicate that your  answer solved my  issue?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the actual solution to the problem for those who'd come after. Not sure if you're supposed to mark the question solved by my answer  so I'll leave it to you. Cheers!